# Route.go doesn't work in form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, form-submit

I'm new to meteor and javascript and I'm developing an app just for fun.

I'm using meteor with ionic.
I have a simple form:

```
   <form>
       ....
      <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Post Title" required>
      </label>
      ....
      <label class="item item-input" >
        <textarea name="message" required></textarea>
    </label>
    ...
    <button class="button icon-left ion-android-upload  button-large create-button button-positive">
       Create
    </button>
    .....
<form>
```

and the relative helper look like this:

```
   Template.boxSubmit.events({
     "click .create-button": function (e) {
       var box = createBoxFromForm($('form').serializeArray());
       Boxes.insert(box);
       Router.go('/');
    }};
```

The record is inserted but there's no redirection to "/".
If I insert:

```
   e.preventDefault();
```

Record is inserted, redirection works but I don't get the basic automatic form validation (null field, with errors reported to users).

Is there a way to have both?

Comment: did you find a workaround for this?

Comment: I had no time to try...it's an after work project, when I will come back at home I will try, tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add a `type="submit"` attribute to your button, and definitely use `e.preventDefault()` in your event handler.

Not 100% sure but I think the default HTML5 form validation is triggered only when clicking on a button which type has been explicitly defined of submit type.